# Search Inside Mongo Database

Tags: mongodb, database

It is the first tie to use non sql database and first time also to use mongo db i need to search inside mongo db that is all i want ,i have a very small task in maintenance of an old project any help ,answer or links will be great .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo can find an answer in it's own website :

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries

and here is an example with java :
http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-hello-world-example/